# ¿Como puedo definir "p" sin que me diga que no esta definido?

Tags: python

¿Como puedo definir "p" (numero de conexiones de entrada de una red neuronal) en Google Colaboratory. Estaba copiando los códigos de este vídeo https://youtu.be/W8AeOXa_FqU pero a partir del minuto 24:20 los códigos que escribe me van mal tengo todo exactamente igual pero a él le funciona y a mi no, me dice que "p" no esta definido y no se que tengo que hacer. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDlKY.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/Perat.png

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_circles


# CREAR EL DATASET
n = 500 
p = 2
X, Y = make_circles(n_samples=n, factor=0.5, noise=0.05)
plt.scatter(X[Y == 0, 0], X[Y == 0, 1], c="skyblue")
plt.scatter(X[Y == 1, 0], X[Y == 1, 1], c="salmon")
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()



# CLASE DE LA CAPA DE LA RED

class neural_layer():

 def _init_(self, n_conn, n_neur, act_f):

   self.act_f = act_f
   
   self.b = np.random.rand(1, n_neur)      * 2 - 1 
   self.w = np.random.rand(n_conn, n_neur) * 2 - 1



# FUNCIONES DE ACTIVACION

sigm = (lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.e ** (-x)),
        lambda x: x * (1 - x))

relu = lambda x: np.maximum(0, X)

_x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
plt.plot(_x, relu(_x))



l0 = neural_layer(p, 4, sigm)
l1 = neural_layer(4, 8, sigm)
# ...

def create_nn(topology, act_f):
  nn = []

  for l, layer in enumerate(topology[:-1]):

    nn.append(neural_layer(topology[l], topology[l+1], act_f))

  return nn 
  
  topology = [p, 4, 8, 16, 8, 4 ,1]

  create_nn(topology, sigm)
```

Comment: Por favor se más especifico, tu pregunta no da un contexto. Le hacen falta muchos detalles, si desea una respuesta debes de añadirlos. Te invito a leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas a formular una buena pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Adjunta el código en formato de texto, copiálo en la pregunta, selecciónalo con el ratón y presiona `Ctrl + K`.

Comment: Una aclaración, la palabra clave para una función anónima es `lambda`. En el apartado de tu código llamado `#FUNCIONES DE ACTIVACIÓN` usas la palabra `lamba`.

Answer (score 1):

Mirando tu código en la captura de pantalla veo dos cosas:

1.- Tienes un error de indentación en `def create_nn` pues hay una `g` en la línea siguiente que no está indentanda y no debería estar ahí. Antes o después el código te fallará ahí.

2.- En tú código en algún punto debes de haber definido `p` con `p = value`. Si no lo has hecho es que te has saltado algún paso del vídeo. En el video explican que "p" es tu valor de entrada, así que el valor debes de asignárselo tú.

Mirando el código que has subido tu error es de nuevo de indentación en `create_nn` después del `return` debes de volver a la posición inicial, es decir:

```
    def create_nn(topology, act_f):
      nn = []
    
      for l, layer in enumerate(topology[:-1]):
    
        nn.append(neural_layer(topology[l], topology[l+1], act_f))
    
      return nn 

topology = [p, 4, 8, 16, 8, 4 ,1]
create_nn(topology, sigm)
```

Cuando defines `p` al principio del código esta definición de la variable no se traslada al interior de las funciones.